# Challenges after upgrading Sitecore from 8.1 to 9.1

Tags: sitecore, upgrade, sitecore8

After **upgrading** Sitecore from **8.1 to 9.1**, I am getting a lot of js errors on a few pages in the experience editor only and the page is not editable. 8.1 The same page was working fine.

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined. And Cannot read property 'show' of undefined.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have custom JS that you run in the Experience Editor? Have you compared your build against a clean Sitecore 9.1 installation to make sure you have all the correct files? It sounds like you either have your own JS file that is referencing something from 8.1, or you have the old Sitecore experience editor JS files somewhere instead of the new ones.

Comment: There is a suggestion on this page with the same error: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19839/sitecore-9-1-experience-editor-throwing-js-errors